# AngularJS factory service returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've tried other answers with the same problem, but none of them worked. I have the issue where I'm calling my factory and I get the `undefined` return.

Controller (main.js):

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','beamAPI', function($scope, beamAPI){
    $scope.debug = 'Debug True';
    $scope.beamFollowers = 1;
    console.log(beamAPI('amtraxtge'));
}]);
```

Factory (beam.js):

```
app.factory('beamAPI', function($http) {
    var APIuser = {};
    APIuser = function(user) {
        $http.get('https://beam.pro/api/v1/channels/' + user).
        then(function(res){
            console.log(res.data);
            return res.data;
        });
    }
    return APIuser;
});
```

Console:

```
undefined       main.js:4
► Object        beam.js:6
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `APIuser()` doesn't return anything. You need to return the promise and in controller wait for promise to resolve before assigning or logging any of the data

In factory

```
   APIuser = function(user) {
      // return $http promise
      return   $http.get('https://beam.pro/api/v1/channels/' + user).
         then(function(res){
             console.log('Factory log',res.data);
             return res.data;
         });
    }
```

In controller

```
beamAPI('amtraxtge').then(function(data){
     $scope.someProperty = data;
     console.log('Controller log',data);
});
```